# Add + before value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to add plus(+) before value.

Code as:

```
function todayplus() {
    var url="./get/invoice.php";
    jQuery('+' $ "#todayplus").load(url);
}
```

Result should be **+ something** (plus before value)

Comment: that is invalid syntax. why do you want to do that ?

Comment: what do you mean by value here??

Comment: Let me guess: you want to adjust the existing `$('#todayplus').load(url)` codeline so that inserted value will be prepended by `+`?

Comment: I need that because I use <h2 id="">.

Comment: That's what you need? `'+' + $("#todayplus").val()`

Comment: @raina77ow sure. In invoice.php there is no + . So I need to add + in jquery. Result should be like + 33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want this?

```
function todayplus() {
    var url="./get/invoice.php";
    $("#todayplus").load(url);
    $("#todayplus").prepend("+");
}
```